# rails generate devise:views NameError: uninitialized constant View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, uninitialized-constant

I have followed the #209 tutorial of railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise?view=asciicast. It was working good until I tried to generate the devise views to customize it (tutorial #210  of railscast)

I did :

```
rails generate devise:views
rails generate devise_views
```

Got the following error :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant View
```

I am using rails 3.1.3, & devise 1.4.7 with warden 1.0.6.
Any ideas ?

Tks Matt

Comment: hi @matthughs did  you get the answer? i'm having the exact same issue and it is killing me!

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue myself. I accidentally typed `rails g devise views` which actually created a new model for devise, and added routes for them. I deleted all of the files that were created, then corrected myself and typed `rails g devise:views` and started getting your exact error.

After a bit of head scratching I ran a `git diff` to see if anything else was different, and indeed it had added a route for "views". Upon deleting that route, and running `rails g devise:views` again, all was well!

Hope this helps!

Comment: hello @counterbeing - thank you for your help: i made the same mistake as you did, i ran rails d devise views to get rid of it all, and now when i sign up a new user i get the same error. any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Definitely worth checking your version control (git?) to see if there are files you don't expect to be there. Also, i've never heard of a  `rails d` command. I know there's a `-d` flag, but it's used to indicate a database type in new projects. Double check the docs on that one... I just looked at `rails --help` and it makes no mention of it there. But, version control is a good bet, assuming you're using it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can find out a list of all the generators by running `rails generate` or `rails g`

The correct generator is:

```
rails g devise:views
```

I can only think that you are having some sort of version conflict.

Does the following work:

```
bundle exec rails g devise:views
```

If not, have you already run:

```
rails g devise:install
rails g devise User
```

Comment: Tks Gazler.I tried all your command lines but always the same :    NameError: uninitialized constant View. The think is that devise sign up,in,out system is working good.